# How can I get the type of element being processed by LINQ-to-XML?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

With LINQ I get four elements out of some XML, each element can have a different name (Book, Magazine, Article).

How do I get the name of the element I'm currently processing, e.g. something like **ElementType()** below:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace TestXmlElement2834
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            XElement content = new XElement("content",
                new XElement("book", new XAttribute("id", "1")),
                new XElement("article", new XAttribute("id", "2")),
                new XElement("book", new XAttribute("id", "3")),
                new XElement("magazine", new XAttribute("id", "4"))
                );

            var contentItems = from contentItem in content.Descendants()
                               select new ContentItem
                               {
                                   Id = contentItem.Attribute("id").Value
                                   Type = contentItem.ElementType() //PSEUDO-CODE
                               };

            foreach (var contentItem in contentItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(contentItem.Id);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class ContentItem
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is [`XElement.Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name.aspx) what you're after? (Use the [`XName.LocalName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.localname.aspx) property to then get the local part of the element name.)

If you could say what you want the output to be, that would help :) (I originally thought you meant the [type of node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xobject.nodetype.aspx) (attribute, element etc), but it'll always be `XElement` in your case...)

Comment: @Randolpho: Yes, I originally thought it was the node type that was required, given the repeated use of the word "type". I've included that in a further edit so that anyone who *does* want that still gets to see it. Upvote for your answer as well though :)

Comment: It's just "Name.ToString()". I was thinking in terms of "Type" as in XmlReader's NodeType, etc. thanks.

Comment: I just want the record to show that even the great Jon Skeet makes the occasional mis-parse. Heh... somebody has to bring The Man down... :)

Comment: Also, on second read it looks like I might be attacking you, so don't think that. I'm only joking around. It's all in good fun, right?   ...right???!?

Comment: Plus... it looks like we are now forced to never give you any more rep. 66.6k is just so darn evil, it must continue!

Comment: @Randolpho: The answer to stopping me from having 66.6K is to give me *more* rep, surely :)

Comment: But... we want to keep you at 66.6k.

Answer (score 4):

You want [XElement.Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.name.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var contentItems = from contentItem in content.Descendants()
                   select new ContentItem
                   {
                        Id = contentItem.Attribute("id").Value,
                        Type = contentItem.Name.LocalName
                   };
```